# How to download Power BI dataset without publishing to web

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm using a calculated column that is an average. The problem is, the average is above the range of possible values, which should be impossible. I made a calculated column that calculates the average star rating (out of a range of 1-5) and the value on a visual is coming up as 6, which shouldn't be possible, even if all the values were 5 stars, which it isn't. So there must be an outlier causing the average to be above the range of possible values, but it isn't in the original data source which Power BI pulls from. The original data source shows me a value of 4.1 as an average, which is within the expected range. But Power BI's dataset has introduced an outlier or (data is missing) that caused the average to become a 6.

I can elaborate on the dax below, but what I want to try to do is pull the dataset down from power bi to figure out why it's calculating its average that way. Looking at the source data, the average is 4.1 and there are no outliers in the source data. So, it's not the source data that's the problem. Basically, I want to find the outlier that's causing the average rating to differ in Power BI.

```
Avg Rating = IF(SUM(data[Total Reviews]) = 0, BLANK(), SUM(data[Monthly Stars])/SUM(data[Total Reviews]))
```

Here's a screencap that shows the two
[relevant columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0VvE.png)

Notice that I had to manually calculate (aka eyeball the columns and type into a calculator then calculate manually) these two columns, which came out to ~4.6. I'm trying to download this dataset to explore it in further detail without having to eyeball the dataset, as the source doesn't show this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the data you have a number of options.

1. Create a new report in Power BI Desktop, and then use the connect to [PBI Dataset option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets) to access that data, in for example, a table. You can create your own report based on the dataset in the service as well.
2. Access that data via [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel), which should allow you to access the data in a pivot table using Excel
3. Use the Export data from the [visual option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data), using this you can download 30,000 rows into a csv, or 150,000 in to xlsx formats

Please note, that these options may not be available to you if you do not have the right permissions in the workspace, or options have been turned off in the Power BI Admin tenancy settings.